# How to explicitly allocate TLS for existing threads when dynamically loading a DLL in Windows?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, thread-local-storage

I have a DLL (Dynamic loaded library) that loads after some time the process been running, I explicitly allocate TLS (thread local storage) as defined in [Using Thread Local Storage in a Dynamic-Link Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/using-thread-local-storage-in-a-dynamic-link-library)
for threads in the `DllMain()` function for every `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` case, but according to [DllMain entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain)

> Note that a DLL's entry-point function is called with this value only by threads created after the DLL is loaded by the process. When a DLL is loaded using LoadLibrary, existing threads do not call the entry-point function of the newly loaded DLL.

some threads exist in the process's context before I load the library, is there a way to allocate TLS for them as well other than the `DllMain` entry point?

Comment: What do you mean by "explicitly allocate TLS"? What does this look like? Show a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @Igor Tandetnik, "explicitly" - meaning, using `TlsAlloc()` to get a TLS index and associating it with a `malloc()` allocated pointer using `TlsSetValue()`, In regards to "implicitly" allocating using the `__declspec( thread )`storage specifier which lets the compiler allocate this memory. I added a link to Microsoft's code example to better explain.

Comment: Initialize the slot lazily, the first time a thread calls into your library and you need the thread-local storage. `TlsGetValue` returns NULL when that thread hasn't set the value - check for that and allocate memory then.

Comment: I do see the issue here.  My understanding is that `__declspec( thread )` is not supported in DLLs loaded via `LoadLibrary`.